# Java split the bits of a long in two parts using bit shifting

Tags: java, bit-shift

I need to split the bits of a number say 9(`1001`) in two equal sized parts `10` and `01` in this case.

My first idea was to just shift it but for the right number I dont get the expected result ,I suspect this is due to the sign(no unsigned in java :( ).

My current code is the following:

```
long num=9;
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(num));
long num1=num>>2;
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(num1));
long num2=num<<2;
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(num2));
```

Output:

```
1001
10
100100
```

Any workaround?

Comment: what do you do if it´s an odd number of bits? let´s say 5

Comment: So... you want to count the bits, and divide based on that?

Comment: That is the correct output: `9 >> 2` is `2` (`10` in binary), and `9 << 2` is `36` (`100100` in binary)).

Comment: @agim ,the number of the bits  to be shifted is not important right now,I will deal with it later.

Comment: Don't use >> to split you should put the bits in a char array and split that way.

Comment: @rgettman ,oh I forgot that the number will not just stick to 4 bits and clip the rest... I feel stupid,what a fail question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the lower part, you need to use bitwise AND... so if you shift right by 2 bits to get the higher part, you need to AND with binary number 11 (two bits as 1) to get the lower part. Here's code which should do it for any shift:

```
long num = 9;
int shift = 2

System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(num));
long num1 = num >> shift;
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(num1));
long num2 = num & ( (1<<shift) - 1);
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(num2));
```

---

Explanation of calculating `num2`, for `shift` 2, *0b* means binary literal, in pseudocode:

```
( (1<<shift) - 1) == ( (1<<2) - 1)  == ( 0b100 - 1) == 0b11 == two bits set
```

From that it should be clear how it will work for any `shift` value.

Answer (score 1):

You could shift `num1` back 2 and the subtract it from `num`. This will give you `num2`.